# Find maximum intensity point from center in all directions in matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, image-rotation

I have images (matrix) in matlab and I look for the maximum intensity point from the center of the matrix in every direction to obtain edges. (I use the gradient of the image and I'm looking for a quadrilateral).

For M (n,m)
My first try was to consider one vector M(1:n/2, m/2), look for the maximum and rotate the image to find all maximums in all other directions.
But : the imrotate function causes many errors (crop or loose) and the reconstructed image doesn't correspond to the shape of the original one.

I tried also to consider vectors directly in the original image from center to all points in the perimeter... but it's not easy!

Do you have an idea to solve this ? Any subtlety in Matlab I don't know?

Thanks guy;

My actual code is

```
 s_im = size(ima, 2)/2;
 ima_max = zeros(size(ima));
 ima_new = zeros(size(ima));    


  for a=0:359
    im_r = imrotate(ima, a, 'crop');
    c= floor(size(im_r,1)/2);
    vect_h1 = im_r(c, 1:c);
    l = length(vect_h1);


    [~, id_h1] = max(vect_h1(:));

    [x,y] = rotatePoint([id_h1, c], [c,c], deg2rad(a-180));       
    ima_max(floor(y), floor(x))= 1;
    ima_new(floor(y), floor(x)) = 1;
```

An error is also that the center computed is not the same in all images...

Comment: unclear what you are trying to do. can you add an example image with and an illustration of what you are looking for?

Comment: Consider the center of the image. I want to find the maximum intensity point of each vectors from the center in all direction.
360 vectors for 360 angle rotation, and find for each one, the position of the maximum et retrieve it in the original image

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind would be to insert your image in a bigger matrix padded with zeros and then apply `imrotate`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use [`improfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/improfile.html) to get the intensity along rays emitting from the center pixel:

```
sz = size(ima);
X = sz(2);
Y = sz(1);
all_end_points = cat(1, [ones(1,Y); 1:Y]', ...
                        [1:X; Y*ones(1,X)]', ...
                        [X*ones(1,Y); Y:-1:1]', ...
                        [X:-1:1; ones(1,X)]' );
cent = repmat( [X/2 Y/2], [size(all_end_points,1), 1]);
all_profs = improfile(ima, all_end_points(:,1), all_end_points(:,2));
```

Now you have all the profiles from the center, you can look for the max intensity along each.

Comment: Hmm why not, but, all_end_points is not in two dimensions... and I need to retrieve the original position of each maximum. I want a final image with all maximums points founded.